# Getting role info from WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to get the role list of a user from the `WSO2 IS` user store through Java.

Could you help advise Which API helps me with this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use remoteUserStoreManager Service for get role list of user [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs

Thanks
Isura